# OpenLayers 4 only getting user's location on localhost

Tags: javascript, openlayers

So, I'm using OpenLayers 4 and trying to get the User location to set a marker on the map. On localhost it works fine, it tracks user's location and set the marker on the map But when I acess the site via local ip from another device it don't even ask the permission to use the GPS.

Here is the code:

```
function initMap(eId) {
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: eId,
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
                new app.generateGeoJSONControl()
            ]),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-47.88281816303313, -15.79413706965552]),
                zoom: 12
            })
        });
        map.on('singleclick', click, this);
        trackMe(map.getView());
    };

function trackMe(view) {
        var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
            tracking: true
        });
        geolocation.on('change:position', function (evt) {
            var coordinate = geolocation.getPosition();
            userLonLat = coordinate;
            setMarker({
                longitude: coordinate[0],
                latitude: coordinate[1],
                id: -1
            }, '/assets/marker-user.png', 1000);
        });
    };


function setMarker(ua, imageSrc, zIndex){
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(ua.longitude), parseFloat(ua.latitude)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            data: ua,
        });
        iconFeature.setId(ua.id);
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [iconFeature]
        });

        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                anchor: [0.5, 27],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 1,
                src: imageSrc
            }))
        });

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: iconStyle
        });

        if(zIndex){
            vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);
        }

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it has something to do with the website certificate. Since my website don't have a certificate the browser don't allow it to get user's location. I tried with Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari, the only one who let the website get user's location was Edge.

Comment: For context, [this requirement was added in Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only). Not sure when the equivalent change was made in other browsers.